# Mostrar contraseña EditText

Tags: android

Tengo una duda respecto al layout, quiero generar una actividad, donde el EditText de la contraseña aparezca un ojo, el cual revele lo escrito, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar un botón que al oprimirse cambiara el input Type del Edittext, cada vez que lo oprimas cambiara de password, a text normal

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de muchas formas, yo optaría por crear una customView que incluyese un editText y un imageButton alineados horizontalmente. Dentro de esta customview puedes hacer la lógica para el evento onClick sobre el imageButton que haga que el editText muestre u oculte el texto de la contraseña. Esa custom view la puedes reutilizar en los dos inputs del formulario sin tener que repetir código ni lógica. Un ejemplo de esto más o menos parecido a lo que quieres hacer o puedes ver aquí [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_components.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/androi

Comment: Si cambia su pregunta, no tiene sentido que pida respuestas y luego cambie la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Puedes hacer un toogleo donde a cada toque en el icono cambie el tipo de campo del EditText, ya sea password o SingleText. Espero te sirva de algo.
Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como comenta el amigo [Webserveis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27387/17862), ya se puede hacer de forma sencilla y nativa con el TextInputLayout usando la librería Android support library 24.2.0.
En tu layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_password_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password_form"
            style="@style/LoginEditText"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/login_sign_in"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Al poner el *inputType* como *textPassword*, te saldrá automáticamente.

Answer (score 4):

Hay muchas maneras de hacer esto, pero por lo que vi en tu imagen deseas apretar un boton y mostrarlas, esta funcion deberia ser suficiente, donde button es el button con el icono de ojo. Y edittext donde escribes tu contraseña.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           switch ( event.getAction() ) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
               editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            break;
            }
            return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

He encontrado lo siguiente a ver si te sirve:

Con la nueva versión de la librería de soporte `Android support library 24.2.0` parece que se puede realizar de está forma:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled = "true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorHint"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_android_white_18dp">
```

- **app:passwordToggleEnabled**: activar o desactivar el botón.
- **app:passwordToggleTint**: para cambiar su color
- **app:passwordToggleDrawable**: asignar el icono

Documentación oficial de [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)

Extraído de [Android password visibility toggle](http://codevscolor.com/2016/08/android-material-design-tutorial-10-password-visibility-toggle/)

Otra manera es usar esa librería [PasswordEditText](https://github.com/maksim88/PasswordEditText) que se ha actualizado para 24.2.0 y puedes asignar el icono con estado visible y no visible, es decir con el ojo, ojo tachado.

Comment: @zhet Esto esta perfecto y usa TextInputLayout como validador!.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tex## Título ##tInputLayout2"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:theme="@style/CampoTexto1"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/etpass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/vector_pass"
    android:drawablePadding="12dp"
    android:hint="@string/etclave"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Una respuesta que solo es código dificilmente puede trascender debido a que no explica como este código soluciona el problema y menos como aplicarlo, por favor lee [answer]

Comment: La propiedad imputType  y passwordToggleEnabled te permiten activar el boton de ver password.

Comment: Una explicación detallada será de mucha ayuda pero en tu respuesta, por favor edita y amplia lo que sea necesario para que tu aporte sea mejor recibido